# Why is WebViewPage in MVC3 abstract?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

What is the point of

```
public class ThemedViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    public override void Execute()
    {

    }
}
```

What am I supposed to do with it? I ask because I've left it empty and the world is a good place and everything appears to work - just updating a demo I'm running this afternoon and this  is a question I'll likely be asked.

Comment: The best solution here is to also declare your class as abstract and *not* overriding the Execute() method at all.

Comment: Good point, coupled with the below answer that makes sense

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Razor works by generating a class that inherits from a base class.  The default class it inherits from is `WebViewPage<T>`.  When you express `@inherits ThemedViewPage<Something>` you're telling the code generator to create a class that then inherits from `ThemedViewPage<Something>`.

You don't actually implement the `Execute` method, as the Razor parser which generate this method.  It's worth reading [Andrew Nurse's Blog](http://blog.andrewnurse.net/CategoryView,category,Razor.aspx), [Ben @ BuildStarted's Blog](http://buildstarted.com/category/razor/) and perhaps even [my own](http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?s=razor) as we've been working recently on building a standalone Razor Templating Engine, so needed to learn how it all worked internally.

Comment: Cool - that's good enough for me, scant documentation about but I wanted this talk to be up to date.

Comment: Do I need to `@inherits` in every view. Is it not *inherited* from the _Layout?

Comment: Four years late, but no, it is not inherited from the layout.